# What is the word 'hallow' meaning here?

Tags: meaning, word-usage

[Merriam-Webster](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/hallow) says,

1. : to make holy or set apart for holy use
2. : to respect greatly : venerate

Then they used the following sentence to give an example.

> [The Gary Fire Department spent more than five hours pouring water
>   into the school's hallowed auditorium](http://www.chicagotribune.com/suburbs/post-tribune/news/ct-ptb-gary-vacant-schools-st-0529-20170528-story.html)

How can a **school-auditorium** become *venerable*?

Comment: It's perfectly normal to use adjectival ***hallowed*** (metaphorically and/or facetiously) in "non-religious" contexts. In any case, the school's auditorium (main hall) would very likely have been used for (religion-based) morning roll call.

Comment: It's an ironic usage - a bit like my saying "someone's dog has just savaged my wife's hallowed flower border". It isn't "hallowed" in the way a church is, but I might refer to it as "hallowed" simply because I know it means a lot to her. The word is also used sarcastically. e.g. "his hallowed football on Saturdays".

Comment: [Collins](https://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/english/hallowed) explains clearly. < hallowed 1. _adjective_ 
Hallowed is used to describe something that is respected and admired, usually because it is old, important, or has a good reputation.
'The hallowed turf of Twickenham is the venue for the Middlesex Rugby Sevens Finals.' // 
'They protested that there was no place for a school of commerce in their hallowed halls of learning.' > It's almost always very advantageous to check in more than one dictionary. And to be precise ('hallowed' probably takes the secular sense more often).

Comment: I think the key is that you didn't look up the right word.  If you'd looked up the actual word which was used, "hallowed", rather than "hallow" then you wouldn't even need to ask the question.  https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/hallowed

Comment: @EdwinAshworth "Turf" of one kind or another (whether it be at Wembley, Ascot, Lords, Wimbledon or Twickenham) has a particular tendency to achieve "hallowed" status.

Comment: @WS2 If there is a problem with moles, it acquires hollowed status.

Comment: @EdwinAshworth No doubt they have a way of dealing with them. The thought of a molehill appearing between the wicket and the crease doesn't bear thinking about. What would the Laws say?

Answer (score 1):

According to http://www.dictionary.com/ hallow could mean:

> greatly revered or respected.
>   For example: "in keeping with a hallowed family tradition"

In this context I don't think hallowed is intended as holy but more so that the school-auditorium is revered or respected. Considering the implication of respect, I would venture to say that hallowed fits correctly in this sentence as school auditoriums may be held in high regard.

Especially considering secondary and post secondary educational facilities, where financial donors, who are held in a high regard and respect, may attach their name, and consequently legacy, to an auditorium.